# Http basic authentication mechanism

Tags: http, authentication, basic-authentication

- After the user requests a protected resource X the server responds
  with code 401.
- The browser prompts the user to inser user-name and
  password and automatically re-send the request to the server with
  those authentication information

My question is : is this process repeated over and over for each protected resource ?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: I mean this is not quantum physics...it should be documented somewhere but I cannot find where, can you help ?

Comment: This can vary by implementation (eg `PreAuthenticate` in .NET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at RFC 2617. There is stated for basic-athentication :

> Upon receipt of an unauthorized request for a URI within the
>   protection space, the origin server MAY respond with a challenge ...

and also

> A client SHOULD assume that all paths at or deeper than the depth of
>   the last symbolic element in the path field of the Request-URI also
>   are within the protection space specified by the Basic realm value of 
>   the current challenge. A client MAY preemptively send the
>   corresponding Authorization header with requests for resources in
>   that space without receipt of another challenge from the server.
>   Similarly, when a client sends a request to a proxy, it may reuse a
>   userid and password in the Proxy-Authorization header field without
>   receiving another challenge from the proxy server.

So, from the server side this may occur at any request the the server deems unauthenticated. If resource Y does not share the prefix that had been yuthenticated with resource X then the server will re-request authentication.

For avoiding this the authentication scheme e.g. could request authentication for a common prefix of the related resources , such that authentication for prefix of resource X also covers resource Y as a prefix. This will allow the client to send the authentication header and cause the server to detect the call as already being authenticated.

Comment: RFC 2617 was obsoleted by newer RFCs (but the answer is still correct)

Answer (score 0):

Once the user input the password, the browser will remember it.
each time the client request the resource at the same website, the browser will send the authentication header automatically.